# Chrome Incorrect viewport size used for media queries when printing

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing, media-queries

I have a strange problem with chrome and printing; when i try to print my responsive website, in the preview of chrome i see the smartphone version while i would like to print the desktop page (in safari or firefox i see, as usual, the desktop version). I tried to set body, html and page with in media print but nothing change... so i made a test page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
            <title>TestPage</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                .testContainer{
                   width:320px;
                   outline:1px solid red;
                }

                @media (min-width: 768px) {
                    .testContainer{
                        width:700px;
                        outline:1px solid green;
                    }
                }
                @media (min-width: 1024px) {
                    .testContainer{
                        width:960px;
                        outline:1px solid purple;
                    }
                }
            </style>
        </head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="testContainer">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commod consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

when i try to print i see the the container red with 320px.

Please somebody can help me to solve this problem?

thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (Chrome printing my site with the mobile instead of the desktop view) when using bootstrap but found out that the bug in chromium is yet to be fixed:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=273306

Only workaround I could find so far was bite the bullet and print the mobile view.